# Proving Cauchy's condensation test by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I was trying to prove Cauchy's condensation test which states that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges iff $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^na_{2^n}$ converges where $a_n$ is a non-negative, non-increasing sequence of real numbers.

Is the following approach viable:

Suppose $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^na_{2^n}$ converges. By the C-S inequality, we have:

$\displaystyle\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{a_k \sqrt{2^{k}a_{2^k}}}{\sqrt{2^{k}a_{2^k}}}\Bigg)^2 \leq \displaystyle\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{a_k^2}{{2^{k}a_{2^k}}}\Bigg)\Bigg($$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^ka_{2^k}\Bigg)$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k \leq  \sqrt{ \displaystyle\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{a_k^2}{{2^{k}a_{2^k}}}\Bigg)\Bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^ka_{2^k}\Bigg)}$

The latter partial sum on the RHS is bounded but can we say anything about the boundedness of the former partial sum? Or is this approach too contrived? Any advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you prove it directly using that $2^n a_{2^n} \ge \sum_{m=2^{n}}^{2^{n+1}-1} a_m$ ?

Comment: Right, thanks. I've understood that approach, but was just wondering if Cauchy's inequality could be used given that we a considering a product of a sequence and a subsequence. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes you can use what you want, but you'll need to use anyway that $2^n a_{2^n} \ge \sum_{m=2^{n}}^{2^{n+1}-1} a_m$ so, indeed, it is useless